# Let $f(x)$ be an even function. Then for all $N \ge 0$ its Taylor polynomial $p_N (x)$ contains only even powers.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be an even function. Then for all $N \ge 0$ its Taylor polynomial
$p_N (x)$ contains only even powers.

true?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

Derivative of an even function is odd and vice versa and odd functions vanish at zero, so it's true that Maclaurin expansion (Taylor at $0$) has only even powers.

That's because $f^{'}(x), f^{(3)}(x), ..., f^{(2k+1)}(x), ...$ are all odd and they vanish in zero.

Comment: why are they vanish in 0?

Comment: @גלרון $f$ is odd  if $ f(-x)=-f(x)$ and for $x=0$, $f(0)=-f(0)$ which implies that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: and if x0 is not 0? we have counter example?

Comment: @גלרון have a look at here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+cosx+around+x%3D1
plenty of odd powers and $\cos(x)$ is an even function

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is even then $f(x)-f(-x)=0$ for any $x$. Assuming
$$ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + a_5 x^5+\ldots $$
we have
$$ 0=f(x)-f(-x) = 2\left( a_1 x + a_3 x^3 + a_5 x^5 + \ldots \right) $$
and this implies $a_1 = a_3 = a_5 = \ldots = 0$ by the unicity of the Taylor polynomial.